# Adding component to my GridBagLayout moves other components far to the right

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm seeing some really weird results when I try to lay out my `JPanel`. Everything works fine before I add the last `JTextField` `subline`:

[image: correct layout before adding last JTextField]

When I add that, the `JTextField` above it moves to the right, so that it begins where `subline` ends:

[image: incorrect layout after adding last JTextField]

Here's the code that creates this layout:

```
public class Opspanel extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6393281054430179953L;
    public Opspanel() {
        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout(layout);
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        add(new JLabel("Vendor ID"), constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        JTextField vendorid = new JTextField();
        vendorid.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
        add(vendorid, constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        add(new JLabel("Email Date"), constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        JTextField emaildate = new JTextField();
        emaildate.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
        add(emaildate, constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 2;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        add(new JLabel("Email Time"), constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 3;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        JTextField emailtime = new JTextField();
        emailtime.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
        add(emailtime, constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 2;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        add(new JLabel("Subject Line"), constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 2;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        JTextField subline = new JTextField();
        subline.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 20));
        add(subline, constraints);  

    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you give some screen shots? It is very absorbing to run someone else code, we need to focus on how we can help, so please provide this additional informations.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll try to attach the screen shots in a bit.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the docs for `GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/),

> Each `GridBagLayout` object maintains a dynamic, rectangular grid of cells, with each component occupying one or more cells, called its display area.

In your code, your grid has 3 rows and 4 columns. You're telling each of your components to occupy exactly one cell, in the position given by `gridx` and `gridy`.

The fact that you don't like some of them "stopping" or "starting" where they do indicates that **you really wanted some of them to occupy more than one cell.**

You're in luck! `GridBagLayout` can do that. You're looking for [`GridBagLayout.gridwidth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#gridwidth):

> Specifies the number of cells in a row for the component's display area.
>
> Use `REMAINDER` to specify that the component's display area will be from `gridx` to the last cell in the row. Use `RELATIVE` to specify that the component's display area will be from `gridx` to the next to the last one in its row.
>
> `gridwidth` should be non-negative and the default value is 1.

---

In your example, you put the "Subject Line" text field in the second column (`gridx = 1`). Since you left `gridwidth` at its default value of `1`, that text field cannot overlap the third or fourth columns. So, if it grows, the whole column must grow with it.

You can let it fill the whole horizontal space by letting it cover multiple grid cells. (If you're familiar with Microsoft Excel or tables in Microsoft Word or similar programs, this is like the "Merge Cells" option.)

To make it cover 3 columns, starting with `gridx = 1`:

```
constraints.gridx = 1;
constraints.gridwidth = 3;
```

Or alternatively, to make it cover all cells from column `gridx = 1` to the right:

```
constraints.gridx = 1;
constraints.gridwidth = GridBagLayout.REMAINDER;
```

Just don't forget to reset `gridwidth` to 1 before you use it to add another component that's supposed to cover only one column!

Comment: May I request you to please help me with an example?